# When you get the message "Object doesn't support this property or method", how do you find out what "Object" is?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, object

When you get the IE error message "Object doesn't support this property or method", how do you figure out what "Object" is? Is it always the same thing? If not, is there a way to use the diagnostic tools or the console to figure out what it is?

Comment: Doesn't it say in which line? (I have no IE so I don't know ;))

Comment: And usually there's a `More >` button or something like that, that indeed shows a line number.

Comment: try to check typeof(object) if you cannot interact with a debugger

Comment: I'm trying to check "typeOf(Object)", but I'm guessing there's more than one object, and I guess it would probably return "object".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get at IE's debugging information, you have to enable script debugging:

1. In Internet Explorer, choose Internet Options from the Tools menu.
2. In the Internet Options dialog box, click the Advanced tab.
3. On the Advanced tab, under Browsing, clear Disable Script Debugging.
4. Click OK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241741%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

If you have IE 8 or above, you can use their developer tools to debug:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd565625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: This is a good answer as far as getting the tools turned on; I'll accept it. I was hoping for more detail on how the tool is used--how you get the tool to give you more detail about what the 'Object' is. I'll go back to the code and try running it with the script debugger enabled.

Comment: Thanks! It really depends on what the problem is.  The error you're seeing happens whenever you have foo.bar() and the 'foo' isn't an object, or doesn't have a 'bar' property.  This would happen, for example, if foo is undefined or null, or if 'this' isn't the object you expect ('this' defaults to 'window' for event handlers in IE).  Those are my best guesses given the info available.  The debugging tools should point you to the line causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and same message.
It turns out the issue is not with coding but with settings of IE. All I had to do was reset IE from Tools => internet options => advanced => reset (including personal settings) That did it for me. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by deselecting 'Enable native XMLHTTP support' in Internet Options (Tools>Internet Options>Advanced>Security)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue due to IE GPO,

strangely enough; IE's addon management GPO breaks MMC and *.MSC.

`GPO\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Security Features\Add-on Management\All Processes` (enabled) Results in,

An Error has occurred in the script on this page.

```
Line: 5
Char: 5
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ConnectTo'
Code: 0
URL: res://C:\WINDOWS\system32\mmcndmgr.dll/views.js
```

More on that [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/683c2fda-a354-430b-b92c-a721dc164e24/solved-mmc-error-one-or-more-activex-controls-could-not-be-displayed-or-object-doesnt-support?forum=win10itproapps).